# How to find out how many hours a drive has been used?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

How can I check how many hours a drive has been used for? I looked in Drive Utility but I didn't see it in the smart data. Is there a better way or program for this?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by hours on the drive?

Comment: WoW! fast reply. I was looking for how many hours the drive has been used. Hopefully, this will help determine if the drive had a hard use life or rarely used. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`smartctl -A <device>` as root from the command line will show you SMART parameter 9, "Power_On_Hours", if the drive supports it.

Comment: If you don't have installed you have to write `sudo apt-get install smartmontools`